# Issue in Bot-Authentication Sample using C#, SignIn Prompt is popping up

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I'm using the below link for bot authentication https://blog.try-it.dev/azure-bot-authentication-using-okta-identity/.

I have configured all the required details in Portal, OKTA and ngrok is working fine.

I'm using able to run the bot, but when I try to signin it give error,

[image: bot screenshot]

this is the stack trace.

```
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.UserToken.<GetTokenWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.UserTokenExtensions.<GetTokenAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.UserTokenClientImpl.<GetUserTokenAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.UserTokenAccess.<GetUserTokenAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.OAuthPrompt.<BeginDialogAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.<BeginDialogAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.MainDialog.<PromptStepAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in D:\Practice\Bot\BotBuilder-Samples-main\BotBuilder-Samples-main\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\18.bot-authentication\Dialogs\MainDialog.cs:line 49
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.<OnStepAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.<RunStepAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.<BeginDialogAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.<BeginDialogAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.LogoutDialog.<OnBeginDialogAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in D:\Practice\Bot\BotBuilder-Samples-main\BotBuilder-Samples-main\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\18.bot-authentication\Dialogs\LogoutDialog.cs:line 31
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.<BeginDialogAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.<BeginDialogAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.<InnerRunAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.<InternalRunAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.<InternalRunAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.DialogBot`1.<OnMessageActivityAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in D:\Practice\Bot\BotBuilder-Samples-main\BotBuilder-Samples-main\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\18.bot-authentication\Bots\DialogBot.cs:line 47
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.ActivityHandler.<OnTurnAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.DialogBot`1.<OnTurnAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in D:\Practice\Bot\BotBuilder-Samples-main\BotBuilder-Samples-main\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\18.bot-authentication\Bots\DialogBot.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.<ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.<RunPipelineAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
```

What am I missing..
I have an APPId, Password and OAuth Connection name as well.

Comment: Could you post the actual error message as well, not just the stack trace?

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "Error retrieving token: ce5bb5f04177e84aa6e241978345fdd8."
  }
} @AP01 sorry, I didn't check the comment. this is what I got as the response

Comment: @AP01 above is the error.

Comment: Make sure you've configured your AppId, AppPassword, and other settings in the bot correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use the OAuth gen 2 authentication and add the client ID and client secret ID of the channel of the bot framework.

Get the credentials from OKTA which are relevant to authentication and make it available to azure active directory for the same client ID.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Adding the role to the user and making the role as at least co-administrator is the procedure need to be added.